# Win API, service receiving system shutdown signal

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, windows-services

How can a windows service receive shutdown signal?
The following logic *works only when system reboots*, service does not act when system is shut down.

I have attached code snippets below, but for the furthure clarity --> [GitHub](https://github.com/WasifRazaSyed/Project_Switch/tree/main/Windows_Service) repo

I have tried:

1.Manipulating `WaitToKillServiceTimeout` registry key under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`.

2.Using `SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN` and `SERVICE_ACEEPT_PRESHUTDOWN` control codes once at a time.

3.SERVICE_PRESHUTDOWN_INFO is used to increase the timeout.

The desparate attempt to get the desried output has led me to try `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine, TRUE);`  function which is meant for console applications.

Following is the code I am using in my application written in Qt framework for C++:

```
VOID WINAPI SVC_MAIN( DWORD dw, LPWSTR * lp)
{
    Q_UNUSED(dw);
    Q_UNUSED(lp);

    status_handle=RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExW(SVCNAME, (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX)HandlerEx, nullptr);

    if(!status_handle)
    {
        Event_Report(LPWSTR("RegisterServiceCtrlHandler"));
        return;
    }

    status.dwServiceType=SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    status.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN;
    status.dwCurrentState=SERVICE_RUNNING;
    status.dwWin32ExitCode=NO_ERROR;
    status.dwServiceSpecificExitCode=0;
    status.dwCheckPoint=0;

    if (SetServiceStatus(status_handle, &status) == FALSE)
    {
        Event_Report(LPWSTR("[ServiceCtrlHandler] SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    init();
}
```

```
void init()
{
    int argc=0;
    char *argv={nullptr};
    QCoreApplication a(argc, &argv);
    w=new worker(&a);
    QObject::connect(&a, &QObject::destroyed, w, &QObject::deleteLater);
    a.exec();
}
```

```
BOOL WINAPI HandlerEx(DWORD dwControl, DWORD dwEventType, LPVOID lpEventData, LPVOID lpContext)
{
    switch (dwControl)
    {
    // Handle the STOP control code
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
    {
        if (status.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_RUNNING)
        {
            return ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
        }

        status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        status.dwWaitHint = 20000;

        if (SetServiceStatus(status_handle, &status) == FALSE)
        {
            w->Log("set service error");
            Event_Report(LPWSTR("[ServiceCtrlHandler] SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }

        int result=w->shutdown();
        while(!result)
        {

        }

        status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        status.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        status.dwCheckPoint = 0;
        status.dwWaitHint = 0;

        if (SetServiceStatus(status_handle, &status) == FALSE)
        {
            w->Log("set service error");
            Event_Report(LPTSTR("[ServiceCtrlHandler] SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }
        return NO_ERROR;

    }

    case SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN:
    {
        status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        status.dwWaitHint = 20000;

        if (SetServiceStatus(status_handle, &status) == FALSE)
        {
            w->Log("set service error");
            Event_Report(LPWSTR("[ServiceCtrlHandler] SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }

        int result=w->shutdown();
        while(!result)
        {

        }

        return NO_ERROR;
    }

    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
    {
        int result=w->shutdown();

        status.dwCurrentState=SERVICE_STOPPED;

        if(SetServiceStatus(status_handle, &status)==FALSE)
        {
            w->Log("set service error");
            Event_Report(LPWSTR("[ServiceCtrlHandler] SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }
        return NO_ERROR;
    }

    case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
    {
        return NO_ERROR;
    }

    default:
    {
        break;
    }
    }
    return ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
}
```

Comment: When you want to handle SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN shouldn't you request it with [SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_status) ?

Comment: Yeah, but I am now using SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN which is better than SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN in my case as it gives me desired output but only when system reboots. We can't use both of them.

Comment: Note that `shutdown` and `shift+shutdown` are different -  see the system up time in Task Manager.  `shutdown` now does (since Windows 10) a partial suspend to disk, which might only suspend your service to disk.

Comment: Shift+Shutdown worked, now how can I handle this situation? I want the code to work without differentiating shutdown and shift+shutdown.

Comment: If the service is suspended to disk and then restored to a running state, is there anything you need to do?  As far as the service is concerned the computer has not been shutdown.

Comment: Now looking into `SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT` for getting power events. It might work.

Comment: disabling fast startup works, nothing else worked.